# Insert Nodes in the Linked List

Tags: java, nodes

I have an insert method that inserts a node into a linked list. The problem is, every time a node is added, the recent node added becomes the head node and loses the nodes before it. How do I keep the head node value and link it to the next nodes that will be added?

Here's the code

```
    private Node<D> startOfNode;
    private Node<D> endOfNode;  

    public void insert(D data) throws ListOverflowException {
    Node<D> head = new Node<>(data);
    startOfNode = head;

    if (head.getData() != null) {
        Node<D> node1 = new Node<>(data);
        head.setNext(node1);
        endOfNode = node1;
    }
}
```

I use this print method:

```
public void printList() {
    Node<D> curr = startOfNode;
    int counter = 0;

    while(curr!=null) {
        System.out.println("Item " + counter + " :" + curr.getData());
        curr = curr.getNext();
        counter++;
    }
    System.out.println("Item " + counter + " :" + null);
}
```

Both of these methods belong to the same class. I use a tester class and instantiate the said class.

When I try to to add two nodes with values of 20 and 30, I get this result:
Item 0 :30
Item 1 :30

But it's supposed to be:
Item 0 :20
Item 1 :30

Comment: how you print the list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are resetting the head everytime you add a data in your insert method.

You can iterate from  the startnode and when you find the next node is null, you can add a new node and attach it to the current node's next and just update the endNode.

Or you can go to the endnode and attach a new node with the passed value.

A simple way of doing it is shown below:

```
private Node head;
private Node tail; 

public void insert(int data){
    Node newNode = new Node(data); //Create
        
    if(tail != null) { //Link
        tail.next = newNode;
    }       
        
    if(head == null) {  //Update head.
        head = newNode;
    }
        
    tail = newNode;  //Update tail.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't reset the head while inserting. Code below should work properly:

```java
    private Node<D> startOfNode;
    private Node<D> endOfNode;  

    public void insert(D data) throws ListOverflowException {
    iterator = startOfNode;
     
    if(iterator == null) {
    startOfNode = new Node<D>(data);
    endOfNode = startOfNode;
    return;
    }
    while(iterator.getNext() != null) {
        iterator = iteartor.getNext()
       }
   Node<D> end = new Node<>(data);
   iterator.setNext(end);
   endOfNode = end;
   }
```